# OpenELEC : "cp: can't stat '/flash/SYSTEM'"

Tags: linux-mint, dual-boot, uefi, openelec

I'm buidling an HTPC and would like to multi-boot it with OpenElec + Mint; with EFI boot.

I use the OpenElec 7 Beta 1 (OpenELEC-Generic.x86_64-6.95.2.img.gz) as my Intel NUC6I3SYH is not supported below.

All my problems comes from this : the installation of OpenElec is quite simple (which is nice but), you don't have any choice : you have to format your disk.

It creates 2 partitions :

- 1 partition of ~500 Mo with the system (FAT16; "SYSTEM")
- 1 partition of the remainging space for the datas (EXT4; "STORAGE").

So when you wan to add another OS to it, it's quite a pain : you have to resize/reorder partitions, etc.

During my last attempt, I started by installing OpenElec normally; and I made an image of the "SYSTEM" partition, that I stored on an external hard drive (using Mint live CD).
I haven't made an image of the "STORAGE" partition since it was empty.

> sudo cat /dev/sda1 > /media/Mint/Backup/OESystem.iso

I formatted the disk, and installed Mint regulary.
I recreated the OpenElec partitions with gParted; and loaded the iso image on it.

Note that the "SYSTEM" partition was FAT16 and so I had problems when extending it with gParted (a was warned about a cluster size problem or something); so I used EXT4 for it.

Then; I installed [reFIND](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) to manage the UEFI boot; and when I boot OpenElec, I got this message :

> cp: can't stat '/flash/SYSTEM'

I know my installation has been a little experimental, but I don't see why it should not work.

Also, I saw a lot of other people getting this error, but there were no answer about this particular problem.
The only thing interesting I read was [this on Github](https://github.com/OpenELEC/OpenELEC.tv/issues/2809), but it's too technical for me and I didn't understood it.

I suspect that the problem comes from partition access permissions, or from the OpenELEC boot system.

Comment: + does the "clean install" method described [described here](http://openelec.tv/forum/124-raspberry-pi/64701-resizing-system-partition#75689) 2 years ago still is working ?